# mongodump: How do I exclude gridfs from being dumped

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

How do I exclude gridfs fs.chunks and fs.files from being processed via mongodump?

-daniel

Comment: What have you tried or researched? [This link](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongodump/#std-option-mongodump.--excludeCollection) popped up right away when I searched for "mongodump exclude collections"

Comment: @user20042973 The gridfs is prefixed by a bucket name  "fs."  So the collection names are fs.chunks and fs.files.  However, these cannot be excluded or excluding them doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

--excludeCollection fs.chunks --excludeCollection.fs.files